# The drop-down menu does not display results

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, dll, menu

I have a problem with the drop down menu. After adding the following script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">

<script>
    $("#searchart").chosen();
    $("#searchcity").chosen();
    $("#searchstore").chosen();
    $("#searchwork").chosen();
    $("#searchava").chosen();
</script>
```

It currently looks like this:
[image]

This is how the code looks similar to each field:

```
<?php
 include_once('connection.php');
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM avaiable");
                        
echo"<select id='searchava'>";
echo"<option> -- Select Avaiable Type -- </option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option>$row[AvaiableName]</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
                        
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I tried in every way to fix the menu but without success. I'm sure I'm messing with something small but I don't see it.

after Inspecting the item:
[image]

Comment: I am not seeing any such behaviour . Are there error in console ?

Comment: there are no errors in the console.

Comment: do one thing see inspect element tab if that chosen html is generated or not when you intialize it .

Comment: Before adding these libraries, everything worked correctly. The results from the database were visualized.

Comment: After inspecting the element I noticed that against the id there is style = "display: none;"

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved! The width was 0 pixels